# Attempting to run multiple simulations of the Gillespie algorithm for a set of stochastic chemical reactions, in Python, in less than 10 minutes

Tags: python, loops, optimization, runtime

I have written Python code that generates a plot. In the code below, when I set `maxtime = 0.1`, the program takes ~50s and when I set `maxtime = 1`, it takes ~420s. I need to run it for `maxtime = 1000`.

I am familiar with Python syntax and writing "Matlabic" code, but am lost in writing natively "Pythonic" code. As a result, I need help in **optimizing this code for runtime, specifically in the two outer `for` loops and inner `while` loop.**

1. How can I make the code suitable for use with Numba or Cython?
2. If that's not possible, do I need to use functions, or `map`, or `lambda` statements?

Unfortunately, my Spyder IDE for Python is freezing up everytime I try to profile the code. I would include those details if I could!

The code is below. Thanks.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab as pl
import math

maxtime = 1
Qpvec = np.logspace(-2,1,101,10)
lenQp = len(Qpvec)
delta = 1e-3
P0vec = Qpvec/delta
SimNum = 100
PTotStoch = np.zeros((SimNum,lenQp))
k_minus = 1e-3
k_cat = 1-1e-3
k_plus = 1e-3
zeta = 1e-4
D0 = 10000
kappa_M = (k_cat+k_minus)/zeta
QpDeg = np.true_divide(1000*D0*Qpvec*k_cat,1000*Qpvec + kappa_M)

for lenQpInd in range(0,lenQp):
    for SimNumInd in range(0,SimNum):
        Qp = Qpvec[lenQpInd]
        P0 = P0vec[lenQpInd]
        DP0 = 0
        P = math.floor(P0)
        DP = DP0
        D = D0
        time = 0

        while time < maxtime:
            u_time = pl.rand()
            u_event = pl.rand()
            rates=np.array([Qp,zeta*P*D,k_minus*DP,k_cat*DP])
            PTot = P + DP
            kT = np.sum(rates)
            tot = np.cumsum(rates)
            deltaT = -np.log(1-u_time)/kT
            time += deltaT
            if time > maxtime:
                PTotStoch[SimNumInd,lenQpInd] = PTot
                break
            elif u_event*kT < tot[0]:
                P += 1
            elif u_event*kT < tot[1]:
                P -= 1
                DP += 1
                D -= 1
            elif u_event*kT < tot[2]:
                P += 1
                DP -= 1
                D += 1
            elif u_event*kT < tot[3]:
                DP -= 1
                D += 1   

PMean = PTotStoch.mean(axis=0)
PStd = PTotStoch.std(axis=0)

plt.figure(0)
plt.plot(Qpvec,PMean,marker=".") 
plt.errorbar(Qpvec,PMean,yerr = 2*PStd, xerr = None)
plt.show()
```

Comment: This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network: codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Oh ok! Didn't know. Just posted there.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong at first glance. Without knowing about your requirements it's difficult to tell where possible optimizations may be.

Comment: @JosepValls I need to have the program run in less than 10 minutes, for `maxtime = 1000`. I realize this is a stretch, but believe in the power of optimization

Comment: Not saying it can't be done. It's just difficult for us to tell without knowing anything about you are trying to accomplish (besides runtime requirements).

Comment: For profiling I usually use http://www.vrplumber.com/programming/runsnakerun/

Comment: By the way, not sure what you mean by your second question. You are not using any list comprehensions which is what you could replace with map.

Comment: Will look into your link - this program implements a stochastic model of chemical reactions, runs 100 simulations for each of 101 values of the input parameter, `Qp`. The `maxtime` is the desired total time for the set of reactions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try compiling with [PyPy](http://pypy.org/).  It doesn't look like matplotlib is supported so you may have to include this part in a separate file.